# New Line Character is not shown in TextBox

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I have a form as shown in image below:

[image]

Now, When user clicks on `Save As Template`, I save the text of the textbox in XML File. The Code I use to save this text in XML File is :

```
public static void SaveTemplate(string Message)
{
    XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(templatesPath);

    xmlDocument.Element("Templates").Add(
        new XElement("Template", new XAttribute("Id", xmlDocument.Root.Elements("Template").LastOrDefault() != null ? int.Parse(xmlDocument.Root.Elements("Template").LastOrDefault().Attribute("Id").Value) + 1 : 1),
            new XElement("Body", Message)));

    xmlDocument.Save(templatesPath);
}
```

The text saved in XML file looks like:

[image]

After that User may do whatever he wants. When User runs my application again, the textbox is empty. So, he will click on `Load Template` Button. At that time the text is shown in datagridview:

[image]

Now, User clicks on `Select Template` and the text from DataGridViewCell is copied to textbox again. But the text does not contain new lines. Look at the image below:

[image]

Does anybody experienced the same problem in past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to replace `\n` with `Environment.NewLine`like:

```
_frmMsgDetails.MessageBody = dgvTemplates.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString()
                                                .Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
```